# Is there any result on the "counting" of minimal atlas?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Take a differentiable manifold $M$. Define $\eta(M)$ as $\min\{\#\mathfrak{A} \mid \mathfrak{A} \text{ is an atlas for $M$}\}$. For example, if $M=S^n$, we have that $\eta(M)=2$, since $S^n$ is compact and $2$ charts (the stereographic projections) are enough to cover $M$.

Is $\eta(M)$ known for a wide range of manifolds? Is it somehow manageable to compute it? Does there exist any technique?

Comment: Let's start with a few easy intermediate questions, perhaps you already know their answers? (1) Does every manifold have a finite atlas? (2) Can we at least find the answer for some completely classified family of manifolds, like the compact surfaces?

Comment: You should be specific here. In a lot of presentations the domains of the atlas are chosen to be open sets in $\Bbb R^n$. For say orientable closed surfaces and 3-manifolds one gets that $\eta(M)=2$ (using Heegard diagrams for the 3-manifolds).

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a number concerned with the minimal amount of open subsets to cover $M$ which satisfy contractability in $M$ --- the [Lusternik Schnirelmann category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusternik%E2%80%93Schnirelmann_category) $cat(M)$. This gives you (at least with my definitiong of a chart)

$$
cat(M)\leq \eta(M).
$$

There are a lot of interesting techniques presented in the literature for this, which might be interesting for you. Note that historically this category was originally defined for closed subsets, so literature can be non-consistent. Note that $cat(M)$ is also related to other fields such as Morse theory.

Comment: It is good to know that this category is very difficult to compute, but one can obtain estimates. For example a lower bound on the LS category is the cuplength of the manifold.

Comment: It is indeed hard to compute, however there are some bounds and nice properties. To add an upper bound, you can take the number of critical points of any Morse function.